# Javascript function to set 'display' attribute works in some situations and not others

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In my program I either display or not display certain elements based on the user's selection of a set of radio buttons. I use the "onclick" atribute to call a Javascript function "hideshow(e,x)" that takes as as the first argument the class name of the elements to be displayed/not-displayed and as the second argument either 'none' or 'inline'. That seems to be working fine.

But sometimes, I already know which elements should be displayed, so I do not display the radio buttons and just want to call hideshow(e,x) directly. By putting an ALERT statement in the function, I know the function is, in fact, being called and is receiving the correct parameters. Yet the visiblity of the elements does not change.

Can anyone explain this, and tell me how to fix it?

Here is the code. I am using the variable $isperson to determine if the radio :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Visibility Test</title>
    <script>
    function hideshow(element,x){
        alert ("in hideshow, element:"+element+", x:"+x);
        $(element).css("display",x);
        var telement = element+"-";
        var tx="";
        if(x=="none"){tx="inline";}else{tx="none";}
        $(telement).css("display",tx);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?
$isperson=1;
        if($isperson){
            echo " ready to use hideshow <br>";
            ob_start();
            echo "<script>setTimeout(hideshow('.personInput','inline'),1)</script>";
            ob_end_flush();
         }else{
            echo "<input type='radio' name='bizorper' value='business' onclick=\"" . "hideshow('.personInput','none')" . "\" id='business' checked> Business/organization";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='bizorper' value='person' onclick=\"" . "hideshow('.personInput','inline')" . "\" id='person'> person <p>";
         }
?>

    <p class="personInput" style="display: none"> Normally doesn't display if radio button is 'business', but should if radio button is 'person' or $isperson=1<p></p>  

    <p class="personInput-" style="display: inline">Normally Displays, unless radio button is 'person' or $isperson=1</p> 
    <p class="personInput" style="display: none">Normally doesn't display 2;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an aside, using `console.log(var)` is often more convenient than `alert()`

Comment: Why are you using php output buffering to print a simple string? That's not needed.

Comment: the problem with using jQuery is that it allows you to do things like `$('.someClassThatDoesNotExist').dosomethinghere()` ... and there's absolutely no error with this, because it's how jquery rolls ... if you tried this with palin ol' javascript equivalent, you would possibly need to test if you have any elements to work with before blindly doing something with them.

Answer (score 0):

Put the PHP code that outputs the JavaScript *below* the elements that need to be displayed/hidden.

Your function is being executed before the elements are rendered. You did include a timeout, but it's only set to 1 millisecond. Moving the script down should allow you to get rid of the timeout altogether.

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. (I guess it should have been obvious.)